# Oracle SQL Insert whit Case Select

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, insert

I'm new in this site and I have another question. In this case, it is from Oracle SQL, Insert operation with a CASE.
My SQL insert's code is:

```
INSERT WHEN (SELECT TB0083_DS_TIPODISPOSITIVO FROM TB0083_TIPODISPOSITIVO WHERE TB0083_ID_TIPODISPOSITIVO = (SELECT FOR_DISPOSITIVO FROM TFORPD01 WHERE FOR_CODIGO = &FORNECEDOR))='TIV' THEN
INTO TTRAPD01 (TRA_CODIGO,TRA_CODBARRA,TRA_CODLOC,TRA_CODCON,TRA_DATLOC,TRA_CODCAIXA,TRA_STATCOND,TRA_DT_CRIACAO,TRA_NM_USUARIOCRIACAO,TRA_DT_ALTERACAO,TRA_NM_USUARIOALTERACAO,TRA_CD_CONTA,TRA_CODCTR,TRA_TRANSACAO_ONLINE,TRA_TIV_HEXA,TRA_TIV_BINARIO,TRA_CD_DISPOSITIVO,TRA_DATSINC,TRA_ID_TPSEGREG,TRA_FORNECEDOR,TRA_STATUS) 
VALUES (&NUMEROIDENTIFICADOR,&CODIGOBARRAIDENTIFICADOR,&CODIGOPONTOVENDALARM,259,SYSDATE,&CODIGOCAIXA,0,SYSDATE,&USUARIOLOGUEADO,SYSDATE,&USUARIOLOGUEADO,422,1,0,&TIVHEXA,&TIVBINARIO,423,SYSDATE,3,&FORNECEDOR,1)
ELSE
INTO TTRAPD01 (TRA_CODIGO,TRA_CODBARRA,TRA_CODLOC,TRA_CODCON,TRA_DATLOC,TRA_CODCAIXA,TRA_STATCOND,TRA_DT_CRIACAO,TRA_NM_USUARIOCRIACAO,TRA_DT_ALTERACAO,TRA_NM_USUARIOALTERACAO,TRA_CD_CONTA,TRA_CODCTR,TRA_TRANSACAO_ONLINE,TRA_TIV_HEXA,TRA_TIV_BINARIO,TRA_CD_DISPOSITIVO,TRA_DATSINC,TRA_ID_TPSEGREG,TRA_FORNECEDOR,TRA_STATUS) 
VALUES (&NUMEROIDENTIFICADOR,&CODIGOBARRAIDENTIFICADOR,&CODIGOPONTOVENDALARM,259,SYSDATE,&CODIGOCAIXA,0,SYSDATE,&USUARIOLOGUEADO,SYSDATE,&USUARIOLOGUEADO,422,1,0,&TIVHEXA,&TIVBINARIO,423,SYSDATE,2,&FORNECEDOR,1);
```

This script doesn't found.
I need to fix it, because I need to change the value of field **TRA_ID_TPSEGREG** depends on the value of:

```
SELECT TB0083_DS_TIPODISPOSITIVO FROM TB0083_TIPODISPOSITIVO WHERE TB0083_ID_TIPODISPOSITIVO = (SELECT FOR_DISPOSITIVO FROM TFORPD01 WHERE FOR_CODIGO = &FORNECEDOR)
```

If value is 'TIV' then it inserts 3 in that position, else it inserts 2 in those field. 
Thanks!!

Comment: What are you trying to do?  I can't make sense out of the SQL code.  It is quite far from correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

There's PL/SQL `INSERT WHEN` command:

Try this:

```
INSERT FIRST 
     WHEN TB0083_DS_TIPODISPOSITIVO = 'TIV' THEN
          INTO TTRAPD01
               (
                    <COLUMN_NAME1>,<COLUMN_NAME2>......
               )
               VALUES
               (
                    <COLUMN_VALUE1>,<COLUMN_VALUE2>.....
               )
     ELSE
          INTO TTRAPD01
               (
                    <COLUMN_NAME1>,<COLUMN_NAME2>......
               )
               VALUES
               (
                    <COLUMN_VALUE1>,<COLUMN_VALUE2>.....
               )
SELECT TB0083_DS_TIPODISPOSITIVO
          FROM TB0083_TIPODISPOSITIVO
          WHERE TB0083_ID_TIPODISPOSITIVO =
               (SELECT FOR_DISPOSITIVO FROM TFORPD01 WHERE FOR_CODIGO = &FORNECEDOR
               );
```

For eg:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST ( ID NUMBER);
INSERT FIRST
   WHEN dummy  = 'Y' THEN
      INTO TEST
         VALUES(222)
   ELSE 
      INTO TEST
         VALUES(555)   
select dummy from dual;
```

The above query will insert 1 ROW on the very first condition satisfy.  See more: [>>here<<](http://psoug.org/snippet/INSERT-FIRST-WHEN_591.htm)